# SQL using variable to control required statements in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I have a table from following codes.

```
SELECT *
FROM df_dbo.VO_Sales
WHERE SaleMethods  not like '%Flash%'
AND (MO_Detail not like 'Month_Adjustment%' OR MO_Detail ='Month_Adjustment_Regulation')
```

If I want a variable for user to control whether the second statement in WHERE statement is required, how can I do something like this?

```
declare @control varchar(3)
set @control= 'Net'

SELECT *
FROM df_dbo.VO_Sales
WHERE SaleMethods  not like '%Flash%'
IF @control= 'Net':
    AND (MO_Detail not like 'Month_Adjustment%' OR MO_Detail ='Month_Adjustment_Regulation')
Else:
    --No additional statements
```

Comment: Just use regular AND/OR.

Comment: Catch-all queries like this result in bad performance. It's better to use an `IF` block and execute the appropriate query each time

Comment: Or, for simple queries you can add `RECOMPILE` to the `OPTION` clause in your query. If the query is complex enough, however, (say with many optional parameters) often a **secure** and **parametrised** dynamic statement can be used to create the query with the correct clauses in the `WHERE`, as then frequently used versions of the query have the benefit of using cached plans. `IF` statements achieve this effect as well, however, result in (a lot) of repetition of code.

Comment: Aside: It is a `where` _clause_ that has a boolean _expression_ to control the rows returned. Not everything is a _statement_. Suggested reading: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean logic:

```
WHERE 
    SaleMethods not like '%Flash%'
    AND (
        @control <> 'Net' 
        OR (MO_Detail not like 'Month_Adjustment%' OR MO_Detail ='Month_Adjustment_Regulation')
    )
```

If you want to implement an "else" logic, you can do:

```
WHERE 
    SaleMethods not like '%Flash%'
    AND (
        (
            @control= 'Net' 
            AND (MO_Detail not like 'Month_Adjustment%' OR MO_Detail ='Month_Adjustment_Regulation')
        )
        OR (@control <> 'Net' AND ...) --> here
    )
```

Comment: First part of codes seem to work, but I don't know why, when I set @control= 'Net', actually I got the results with  (OR (MO_Detail not like 'Month_Adjustment%...). But @control= 'other string' (so @control<> 'Net'), I got he results without  (OR (MO_Detail not like 'Month_Adjustment%...). Should other way around...

Comment: @happyhow: when `@control` is some other string, you get all the records that satisfy condition `SaleMethods not like '%Flash%'`, regardless of the value of `MO_Detail`.

Comment: I think I understand the logic now. My thought was the other way around. Now is clear. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would use `or`:

```
WHERE SaleMethods  not like '%Flash%' AND
       (@flag = 'NO_EVALUATE' OR
        MO_Detail not like 'Month_Adjustment%' OR
        MO_Detail = 'Month_Adjustment_Regulation'
       )
```

Of course, the value could be anything.  I just used `'NO_EVALUATE'` to make the intention clear.

Comment: @happyhow . . . So much for being the first.